# Quill text editor in Angular rendering blockquote in HTML

Tags: html, angular, quill, ngx-quill, blockquote

I am trying to use Quill text editor in Angular to allow users key in blockquote text. When I retrieve the content string, it shows:
[image]

sorry for using a picture as the blockquote will be rendered by Stackoverflow. Back to the topic, I try to pass this string to the HTML page inside a span but it only shows the following:

HTML code:

```
<span>{{content}}</span>
```

it output entire string with the blockquote tag and content instead of render it into a blockquote:

```
<blockquote>testing</blockquote>
```

Comment: have you tried to use innerHtml capability of angular? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding

Comment: @MasoudTahmasebi yes, i did. My problem is solved.

Comment: should I use it as an answer and you may accept it?